# What is the function call_hook does in redmine project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am trying a develop a new project very similar to redmine using ruby on rails, as i'm newbe  to both ruby and rails, i failed to track call_hook function and its use.

Comment: what actually is a hook can you explain??

Comment: Hook is an extension point. You can write plugins that hooks up to certain events and does something.